# Why doesn't my function store the values I want it to when reading data from a file?

Tags: c, file

I'm writing a function which reads data from a file containing 15 series. Each series ends with the value 0.0. `series[].totnr` counts the number of values in each series, `series[].outnr` counts the number of values that is 5% above or below 220, and `series[].average` stores the average value of all the values in the series.

However, when I debug the function, I see that `series[0]` has the values `{totnr= -858993360 outnr= -858993459 average= -107374176.}`

`series[1]` and so on all have similar values. I really need help with this, as I can't see why this is occurring.

Here in the contents of the text file the function is reading from: https://justpaste.it/16orx

```
int read_data(FILE *tsin, struct seriespost series[])
{
  int i = 0;
  float total = 0, number = 0;


  i = 0;
  while (fscanf(tsin, "%f", &number) != EOF)
  {
    total = 0;

    do {
      fscanf(tsin, "%f", &number);
      total = total + number;
      series[i].totnr = series[i].totnr + 1;
      if (number > 231 || number < 209)
      {
        series[i].outnr++;
      }

    } while (number != 0.0);
    i++;
    series[i].average = (total) / (series[i].totnr);
  }
  return i;
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: You _must_ check that `fscanf` returns 1 when reading each number. And don;t forget to zero the array before calling this function.

Comment: And why don't you use the Visual Studio debugger?

Comment: `while (tal != 0.0)` - where is `tal` assigned to? Please show the definition of `series`. What is `serier`?

Comment: You have two separate variables named series and serier. Is this what you really want?

Comment: @paul-ogilvie and @n-m Based on the name of the OP I am guessing that this code was originally written with danish, norwegian or swedish variable names which he then translated to english before posting. Except he forgot to translate `tal` to `number` in one line, and forgot to translate `serier` to `series` in two lines.

Answer (score 0):

"However, when I debug the function, I see that series[0] has the values {totnr= -858993360 outnr= -858993459 average= -107374176.}" You need to make all the array start with 0.